# Word problems on Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In an examination, $80$ students passed in maths, $70$ failed in maths, $90$ failed in science and $20$ failes in both subjects.
How many passed in science$?$
How many passed in both subjects$?$

Comment: Did every student take math?

Answer (score 2):

Let

$a=|\{$pass math, pass science$\}|$

$b=|\{$pass math, fail science$\}|$

$c=|\{$fail math, pass science$\}|$

$d=|\{$fail math, fail science$\}|$

Then $a+b=80,c+d=70,b+d=90,d=20$

We can easily solve to be $b=70,c=50,a=10$.

Hence pass science $=a+c=60$ and pass both $=a=10$

Comment: Nicely explained  +1